# Finding Max and Stdev of the raw tags in Ignition

Tags: ignition, scada-ignition

I have raw tags:

Requirements are:

a) user enters Hours.
b) Based on hours I get a value of "Max" in those hours and a Value of "St Dev" during the given time period.

Please see image:
[Desired Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NSory.jpg)

Database is stored as following schema:

[Database schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NSory.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use an Expression Tag for this. Check out Ignition's video on this: [Creating Expression Tags](https://www.inductiveuniversity.com/video/creating-expression-tags). You link "Desired Result" is an image of a database schema, not the desired result. If you update that image I can help you further. You want to use one expression tag for the *Max* value in your data, and another expression tag for the *St. Dev.* in your data.